# MAAS 1.5+bzr2252-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 14.04 comissioning scripts fail

Tags: 14.04, maas

I am giving a try to MAAS and I have found an issue which I do not know how to tackle. Here is the scenario.

I have installed MAAS 1.5+bzr2252-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

And have setup manually 3 nodes, and the 3 nodes fail in the same manner while being comissioned.

The UI shows the following scripts as failed:

Error output

```
failed [3/6] (00-maas-03-install-lldpd, 99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd, 99-maas-02-capture-lldp)
```

Checking the individual results I assume the script that install the packages is not retrieving the GPG key, but I cannot explain why not since in MAAS settings I have http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu specified as the Main Archive.

```
Commissioning results for supermicro-node6.maas
Script result   Output file     Registered at   Node
[Failed] FAILED     99-maas-02-capture-lldp.err     May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
[Failed] FAILED     99-maas-02-capture-lldp.out     May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
[Failed] FAILED     99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd.err   May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
[Failed] FAILED     99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd.out   May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
OK  00-maas-04-list-modaliases.out  May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
[Failed] FAILED     00-maas-03-install-lldpd.err    May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
[Failed] FAILED     00-maas-03-install-lldpd.out    May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
OK  00-maas-02-virtuality.out   May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
OK  00-maas-01-lshw.out     May 12, 2014, 1:19 p.m.     supermicro-node6.maas
```

**`00-maas-03-install-lldpd.out`**

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libperl5.18 libsensors4 libsnmp-base libsnmp30
Suggested packages:
  lm-sensors snmp-mibs-downloader snmpd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libperl5.18 libsensors4 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 lldpd
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1144 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4566 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libsensors4 libperl5.18 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 lldpd
```

**`00-maas-03-install-lldpd.err`**

```
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.LS3zcm/commissioning.d/00-maas-03-install-lldpd", line 65, in <module>
    lldpd_install(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.LS3zcm/commissioning.d/00-maas-03-install-lldpd", line 49, in lldpd_install
    check_call(("apt-get", "install", "--yes", "lldpd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(u'apt-get', u'install', u'--yes', u'lldpd')' returned non-zero exit status 100
```

Seems this is something trivial with someone with more experience in MAAS. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I met the same issue, pls help to provide the method how to add range?
Example is appriciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this was because I was not using RFC1918 IPv4 addresses (so this was being blocked by `squid-deb-proxy`).

I just added my range to `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl` and restarted the service.

Comment: This definitively solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem here. Turned out to be caused by corrupted cache data ("WARNING: swapfile header inconsistent with available data" in debug log).

rm -rf /var/spool/maas-proxy and starting the maas-proxy service again has solved the problem.